# Does the phrase 'strike the heel' in Gen 3:15 have a deeper meaning?

Tags: genesis, sin, serpent

We read in Gen 3:15 how God curses the serpent:

> And I will put enmity
> between you and the woman,
> and between your offspring and hers; he will crush your head,  and you will strike his heel.

A snake bites at the heel of a person who is on the move with the snake chasing him. When the snake strikes in self defence or otherwise, the man's heel is seldom targeted, unless he has directly stepped on the snake's head. And once the snake's head is crushed by the man, the serpent can no more strike him.

My question is: Does the phrase 'strike the heel' in Gen 3:15 have a deeper meaning other than the literal one?

Comment: This is another example of an "opinion-based" question that needs to remain open. Various hermeneutical approaches naturally yield different results.

Answer (score 3):

The common understanding of the double-crushing (שׁוּף) that would happen is that...

- You (Satan) will crush him (i.e. Satan will crush the Messiah to death)
- He (Jesus) will crush him (i.e. Jesus would crush Satan through his own death)

This conclusion about the passage is so common that it even has its own name: the *Protevangelium* (the first gospel promise).  For a list of early church fathers who concluded this, I suggest [Patristic Interpretation of the Protoevangelium](https://ecommons.udayton.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=2527&context=marian_studies). Here's a list of the early church fathers who concluded that Gen. 3:15 was the first gospel promise:

- Justin Martyr
- Irenaeus, Bishop of Lyons
- Cyprian, Bishop of Carthage
- Serapion, Bishop of Thmuis
- Ephraem, Deacon of Syria

As one reads through the paper, one can easily see how ancient and widespread this conclusion was.

Finally, the answer to your question is: "yes, there is a deeper meaning." This passage is speaking about Satan who crushed Jesus in death, but then, in turn was crushed by Jesus' own death.  We find such beautiful echoes of this in the New Testament:

> “<21> For since death came through a man, the resurrection of the dead
> comes also through a man. <22> For as in Adam all die, so in Christ
> all will be made alive.” (1 Corinthians 15:21–22 NIV11-GKE)

Likewise, a little further on in the same chapter, Paul writes:

> “<54> When the perishable has been clothed with the imperishable, and
> the mortal with immortality, then the saying that is written will come
> true: “Death has been swallowed up in victory.” <55> “Where, O death,
> is your victory? Where, O death, is your sting?” <56> The sting of
> death is sin, and the power of sin is the law. <57> But thanks be to
> God! He gives us the victory through our Lord Jesus Christ.” (1
> Corinthians 15:54–57 NIV11-GKE)

The reason why the early church fathers concluded that Gen. 3:15 was speaking about a future "HE" who would come and crush Satan after he has been crushed is because it's a very biblical thought.

Comment: If the Hebrew for "bruise" occurs twice in Gen .3:15, then that would better explain how Satan did not crush Jesus with death, for death could not hold the sinless Son of God. Death can only claim sinners, so it seems better to think of Jesus being bruised, not crushed by Satan. Jesus will crush Satan, though! YLT intriguingly renders this "he doth bruise thee - the head - and thou doth bruise him - the heel." Does that have merit? +1

Answer (score 1):

There are two matters asked by the OP concerning the "protevangelium" (= "first Gospel") in Gen 3:15

1. **The Verb**

The pertinent verb, occurring twice, is שׁוּף (shuph) meaning, "to bruise or overwhelm".  It occurs just four times in the OT in Gen 3:15 (twice) and Job 9:17 and Ps 139:11.

2. **Double use in Gen 3:15**

Gen 3:15 contains a description of the future relationship between two parties:

- the seed of the woman who is the Messiah to come as per Gal 3:16, 29
- the serpent or the Devil/Satan

The description of this relation between Messiah and Satan contains two elements:

- a general description of "enmity" or unceasing antagonism
- the final outcome of this antagonistic relationship, namely:

(A) The Serpent/Satan will bruise the Messiah's heel; ie, Messiah's wound would be painful but non-fatal.  This is directly alluding to Jesus crucifixion followed by the resurrection; ie Messiah would survive.  See 1 Cor 15:15-20.

(B) The Messiah will bruise the head of the serpent/Satan; ie, fatally destroy the serpent, see Rev 20:9, 10.  That is, Satan would not survive.

Thus, Gen 3:15 really is the Gospel in essence.

Answer (score 1):

The supposed messianic character of the verse is a matter of theological doctrine. But few would disagree with the idea that to "strike the heel" means that humans have the advantage because they can strike from above. The heel need not be taken literally, since - as the OP points out - snakes actually strike at the leg. In that sense, the verse includes the heel is part of the leg.

A Jewish interpretation:

From [Ramban (Nachmanides)](https://www.sefaria.org/Genesis.3.15?lang=bi&with=Commentary%20ConnectionsList&lang2=en)

> This means man will have an advantage over you [the serpent] in the
> enmity between him and you for he will bruise your head but you will
> bruise him only in his heel, with which he will crush your brain.

[Rashi](https://www.sefaria.org/Genesis.3.15?lang=bi&with=Rashi&lang2=en) adds:

> Your sole intention was that Adam should die by eating the fruit first and
> that you should then take Eve for yourself (Genesis Rabbah 20:5), and
> you came to speak to Eve first only because women are easily
> influenced and know how to influence their husbands; therefore “I
> shall put enmity [between thee and the woman]”. As you will have no
> height (not stand erect) you will be able to bite him only on the
> heel, but even at that spot you will kill him.

Christian commentators often  see the verse as prophetic of Satan's putting Jesus death followed by Jesus' ultimate triumph. Catholics tend to see this verse as a prediction of the [role of Mary](https://the-hermeneutic-of-continuity.blogspot.com/2006/12/she-shall-crush-thy-head.html) as a new Eve. Jewish interpreters on the other hand, do not understand that messiah's role as to overcome death but to restore the throne of David. The meaning of the verse is thus a matter of opinion.

Comment: But the Hebrew is clear that the nachash would bruise HIS heel nothing to do with Mary. This was Eve’s word to her and by extension her descendants and about THE ONE descendant. To speak of Mary is clearly eisegesis for enmity existed with the nachash since Eve and all the marked descendants that bore in the Hebrew text the alephtav messianic lineage marker next to their name. If this was spoken of Mary the enmity would have been from Mary’s descendants forward. The last three sentences undo the rest of the post, it’s really not relevant how many utterly wrong interpretative versions there are